# unable to log out from facebook using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

When clicking on my logout link, Facebook ignored the "next" parameter, did not logout and redirect to facebook.com/home.php.  Why?

Below is my code,

```
function signout() { 
                   $this->session->sess_destroy(); 
                     $this->facebook->destroySession(); 
                 redirect($this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => base_url())));                   

    }
```

Comment: Any help please, i am waiting since long time

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the user is not in the current session or if the accesstoken is expired 
You can try by just using the logout url instead of destroying session before the logouturl.

This is for testing :
While redirecting make sure that the $facebook->getuser() is not returning 0 and access token exists.

This happened for me a 6 months back i have done the same thing(making sure that fb session not destroyed before logging out the user) it worked